# How to tell whether item was created in DynamoDB's PutItem?

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I'm evaluating whether DynamoDB will be a good solution for my problem and one requirement I currently have when doing an "upsert" type operation is that I need to know whether the item was created or just updated.

I'm using the AWSSDK for .NET and noticed that the HttpStatusCode returned with the response is always 200 OK, regardless of whether the item was created or updated. Is there a way to determine whether the item previously existed in the same call?

```
var response = await Client.PutItemAsync(request);
```

In Azure DocumentDB, I can accomplish this with Upsert:

```
var response = await Client.UpsertDocumentAsync(selfLink, item);
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Is there an equivalent for DynamoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `request.ReturnValues = ReturnValue.ALL_OLD`.

This will tell DynamoDB to send the "old document" in the response.

Obviously, if there is no "old document" (because the operation is creating a new one), then you will get an empty dictionary:

```
var response = await Client.PutItemAsync(request);
if(response.Attributes != null && response.Attributes.Count > 0)
{
     // It was an update
}
else
{
     // It was an insert
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that was the only option. This would work for me if I could tell it to only select one attribute, say the old partition key. That way it would provide the same info but would only download one attribute and not the entire item. Not sure this is possible though.